# osx - Running a command when iTerm is launched

Tags: macos, iterm

How do I run a command automatically when I open the terminal in Mac?

I tried writing it on the bash.rc file, but it does not seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

.bash_profile is the file to which you want to add your command.